# uplodify in jQuery UI Dialog throws error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uploadify

I am using **uploadify** in asp.net with Upload.ashx file. I search for snippet and it works for single page. If I use jQuery UI dialog it throws some error

> Microsoft jScript runtime error : Object Expected.

**Exception:**

[image]

I am using jQuery version 2.0.

Can anybody throw some light on this issue?

```
   <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jQueryv2.0.3.js") %>'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/uploadify.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ServiceCall.js"></script>
```

Comment: How you have called this jQuery version 2.0 file in your code file?

Comment: yes, I have called in the beginning

Comment: Could you please show me code how you have included js file

Comment: Why you have used ResolveClientUrl in second line?

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't make any difference here, It's in asp.net and sometime i face issue of path on different browser. If I use this then it works for all the browser and on deployment machine as well as productive system. I guess this is the issue with Uploadify+jQuery UI Dialog.

Comment: Please check once you have spelled java script file name correctly for jQuery version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by Replacing this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jQueryv2.0.3.js") %>'></script>
```

to

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jQueryv2.0.3.js" />
```

Comment: Still the problem persist after changing above line

Comment: I have decided not to use uploadify and use PLUpload. Hence want to close / delete this thread. Can anybody guide me for the same

Comment: why you want to delete this thread. Just post new question for new issue. As this is the right answer for existing question so mark it as answer?